# Tahoma persian yea problem

Tags: fonts

I've tried to download and install tahoma font in my Ubuntu 13.04. Everything works fine except there is a problem with two characters ی and ي (d and shift+d in persian layout)

These are displayed incorrectly everywhere (webpages, libreoffice, etc). Wherever it should display ی, displays ي and vice-versa.

My question is if I can swap these two in a font-editor application or something?

Answer (score 3):

Reinstall tahoma fonts, seems like yours' broken.
Enter this in terminal to install Tahoma and some Persian standard fonts. Refresh your browser(f5).

```
wget -c http://hezardastan.sourceforge.net/persianfonts/tahoma.tar.gz
wget -c http://hezardastan.sourceforge.net/persianfonts/bfonts.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-persian-fonts
sudo tar zxvf tahoma.tar.gz -C /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-persian-fonts
sudo tar zxvf bfonts.tar.gz -C /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-persian-fonts
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```